# Points and MultiPoints while generating SHP file with NetTopologySuite

Tags: shapefile, c#, nettopologysuite

I'm trying to generate an SHP file from geometries I have in Postgres DB. Everything goes well with LineString / MultiLineString and Polygon/MultiPolygon, but there is and issue with Point / MultiPoint.

When I try to write an SHP file which contains Point and MultiPoint geometry, I am greeted with an following exception message:
`Expected geometry that implements 'Point', but was 'MultiPoint'`.

To be more specific- there are multiple types of geometries- some of them are regular Point, some of them are Point Z, and some of them are MultiPointZ. It is not an issue with polygons and linestrings- it is the same there (Polygons, mixed with MultiPolygons and PolygonZ and MultiPolygonZ), but when I try to create SHP with points, i get that error I mentioned before.

Code I am using to generate SHP is following:

```
            var shpStream = new MemoryStream();
            var dbfStream = new MemoryStream();
            var shxStream = new MemoryStream();

            var shpStreamProvider = new ShapefileStreamProviderRegistry(
               new ExternallyManagedStreamProvider(StreamTypes.Shape, shpStream),
               new ExternallyManagedStreamProvider(StreamTypes.Data, dbfStream),
               new ExternallyManagedStreamProvider(StreamTypes.Index, shxStream)
            );

            ShapefileDataWriter writer = new ShapefileDataWriter(shpStreamProvider, GeometryFactory.Default, CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance.GetEncoding(1252));

            writer.Header = ShapefileDataWriter.GetHeader(geoms.FirstOrDefault(), geoms.Count);
            writer.Write(geoms);
```

Code breaks on `writer.Write(geoms)` part. Is there anything I am missing? Maybe someone has already faced this issue and has an solution I can apply?

Versions I am using:
NTS: 2.5.0,
NTS.Features: 2.1.0,
NTS.ShapeFile: 2.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the shapefile specification https://www.esri.com/content/dam/esrisites/sitecore-archive/Files/Pdfs/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf points and multipoints are different shape types and they cannot be written into the same shapefile. Shapefile does not make difference between lines/multilines or polygons/multipolygons so they fit into same shapefile.

```
All the non-Null shapes in a shapefile are required to be of
the same shape type. The values for shape type are as follows:

Value Shape Type
0 Null Shape
1 Point
3 PolyLine
5 Polygon
8 MultiPoint
11 PointZ
13 PolyLineZ
15 PolygonZ
18 MultiPointZ
21 PointM
23 PolyLineM
25 PolygonM
28 MultiPointM
31 MultiPatch
```

Comment: Thank you! Already figured it out, was about to post an answer, and your answer was already here. I will post another answer with solution that I used to generate an SHP file.

Answer (score 1):

As @user30184 mentioned,

> points and multipoints are different shape types and they cannot be written into the same shapefile.

Workaround I came up with is to convert regular `Point` geoms to `MultiPoint`. With this approach, you can contain single points and multipoints in one SHP file. So, before adding your NTS Feature to all features you want to write to SHP file, convert `Point` to `MultiPoint`.